# How to do variable specification

Tags: animation

[image]

how can i solve this problem??? I have trouble with variable specification

Comment: Code in copyable form, please.

Comment: Just to reiterate what has been said, generally people do not want to sacrifice their time and energy to parse and answer questions where the poster has not bothered to provide base code in a copyable format to work off of or where the poster has not indicated where exactly they are having difficulties.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, avoid using `Subscript` and related functions for anything other than display.

```
Format[p1] := Subscript[p, 1]
Format[p2] := Subscript[p, 2]
Format[e1] := Subscript[e, 1]
Format[e2] := Subscript[e, 2]
Format[s1] := Subscript[s, 1]
Format[s2] := Subscript[s, 2]

Animate[
 Plot3D[
  (p1 s1 + (1 - p1) (1 - e1))/(p2 s2 + (1 - p2) (1 - e2)),
  {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {p1, p2}),
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 {e1, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {s1, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {e2, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {s2, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]